# Run a command based on stdout frequency

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, expect

I have a program that writes to stdout in a batch of text very quickly, but the output doesn't have a specific output that I can write an expect loop for. Example of stdout of my program:

```
[time:here] random text 1
[time:here] random text 2
[time:here] random text 3
[time:here] random text 4
[time:here] random text 5
[time:here] random text 6
[time:here] random text 7
```

Then it waits until I interact with it, and then it writes to stdout again with the same style of text:

```
[time:here] random text 8
[time:here] random text 9
[time:here] random text 10
[time:here] random text 11
[time:here] random text 12
[time:here] random text 13
[time:here] random text 14
```

The stdout is printed very fast, like within milliseconds, and then there's a wait until I interact with it. Once I interact stdout is written again very quick, and it waits. This repeats until I close the program.

Between the waits I want to send a command to write to another file what time I interacted with the program at (using `echo` or something similar).

Is there any way I can target the "wait" and do the `echo` command after every time there's a wait for my stdout? For example if there's a wait for > than 5 seconds then run the `echo` command, and wait for stdout to change again?

Comment: `expect` can handle a `timeout` event for both `expect` loops and when in `interact` mode, is there a reason those won't fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a blocking read with a timeout to determine when output has stopped. For example, Bash's `read` supports a timeout parameter.  The following script will write a single line if the output from STDIN stops for more than 2 seconds:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r firstline; do
    while read -r -t 2 line; do
        continue
    done
    echo "---- No data in 2 seconds ----"
done
```

The echo could be re-directed to a different log and the script can be modified to echo the data being read from standard in if desired.